# Make Azure storage account and container before running terraform init?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Correct me if I'm wrong, when you run `terraform init` you are asked to name a storage account and container for the terraform state.

Can these also automatically be made with terraform?

Edit: I'm using Azure.

Comment: Maybe not an exact duplicate but I covered this in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39220543/2291321). If you want to use Terraform to create your S3 bucket that you store state in then you have a bit of a chicken an egg situation about where to store the state that creates the S3 bucket. I personally just have a bash script create an S3 bucket, KMS key for encrypting the state files and a DynamoDB table for locking the state and am happy to manage those outside of Terraform for simplicity on bootstrapping.

Answer (score 1):

I usually split my terraform configurations into two parts.

One that creates a storage account with container, with a specific tag (`tf=backend` for example). The second one that creates all other resources. I share a `backend.tfvars` between the two, and in the second one, I get the storage account key using Azure CLI and the previously set tag (that way I don't have to get the key and pass it manually to my second script).

You could even migrate the state of the first terraform configuration once deployed, if you don't want to rely on a local state

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely. You would in general want an S3 bucket for each of your environments, although it's also possible to have a bucket shared across all environments and then set up access controls using bucket policies. Don't create this bucket as part of provisioning other resources, as their lifecycles will likely be different (you would want to retain the bucket for a long time and would be unlikely to want to destroy it).

What you do is you define this bucket in Terraform using local state first. After it is created, you add a remote backend pointing to this bucket.

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.11.7"

  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "my-state-bucket"

    key = "s3_state_bucket"

    region = "us-west-2"

    encrypt = "true"
  }
}
```

After you run `terraform init`, Terraform will ask if you want to migrate the local state file to S3. Answer yes, and after this completes you can delete the local state file, as it's no longer used.

This approach allows you to break out of this chicken and egg situation and still manage all of your infrastructure as code, rather then creating it manually using web console or bash scripts.

Comment: I'm using Azure and I can only see examples scripts using S3 with AWS. This does work with Azure also right?

Comment: Sure, with Terraform you can manage your infrastructure in Azure while storing stuff in AWS. There's also Azure native backend: https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/azurerm.html