# Cannot access Azure backend storage using SSL

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Blob Storage as a state backend, due to new security requirements, I now need to access the azure storage accounts using SSL. This however fails with the following:

> module.core_infra.data.terraform_remote_state.mccp_core_infra:
>   data.terraform_remote_state.mccp_core_infra: storage: service returned
>   error: StatusCode=403, ErrorCode=AuthenticationFailed,
>   ErrorMessage=Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the
>   value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the
>   signature.

Here’s an example configuration:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "terraform_state_account" {
   name                     = "${lower(replace(var.azure_tenant_name, "/\\W|_/", ""))}tfstate"
   resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
   location                 = "${var.azure_location}"
   account_tier             = "Standard"
   account_replication_type = "LRS"
   enable_https_traffic_only = true

   network_rules {
     ip_rules                   = ["masked/24"]
     virtual_network_subnet_ids = ["${azurerm_subnet.mccp_vnet_subnet.id}"]
   }

   tags = {
     environment = "${var.azure_tenant_name} terraform state account"
   }
 }

data "terraform_remote_state" "mccp_core_infra" {
   backend = "azurerm"
   config = {
     storage_account_name = "${lower(replace(var.azure_tenant_name, "/\\W|_/", ""))}tfstate"
     container_name       = "mccp-core-infra-tf-state"
     key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
     access_key           = "${var.azure_mccp_storage_account_key}"
   }
 }
```

I am using Terraform 0.11.11 with azurerm provider 1.33.0. This works just fine without the `enable_https_traffic_only` flag. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does the storage account exist? Right now you have a resource creating the storage account and then a data source trying to access it immediately. This creates an obvious race condition. Using Terraform to manage where you store state (eg Azure blob storage or S3) is tricky as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/q/47913041/2291321 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/39212826/2291321

Comment: It does exist. The data source actually exists and is executed in a separate Jenkins pipeline stage, plenty of time for it to be created. Like I mentioned in my post, I had no issues with this prior to adding the enable_https_traffic_only flag.

Answer (score 0):

The `enable_https_traffic_only` feature would not affect on that error. This works fine with `enable_https_traffic_only` flag in the Terraform v0.12.9
+ provider.azurerm v1.35.0 on my side.

It looks like a credential issue. I can reproduce your issue when the `access_key` is invalid in the data source. You could verify if you could access that storage account blob with that access key or you are getting references from a correct storage account name that hosts the `.tfstate`.

You could also try to delete the local `.terraform` folder and try again as it is mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849179/terraform-back-end-to-azure-blob-storage-errors).